# lighttpd url redirect and security

Tags: perl, security, .htaccess, video-streaming, lighttpd

Cross-post http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=979815

In my server we are streaming videos using lighttpd . Right now everyone who has the link to the video is able to stream the video and see. I want to assure security of the videos so that not everyone can watch the videos. I am thinking about creating a user specific and video specific md5sum which could be send along with url so that only video stream for that particular url request.

For example

Let us assume that now everyone can see the video in the following link

http:/xyz.com/musiv-video/video.mp4

According to my logic the following url should only stream videos

http:/xyz.com/musiv-video/video.mp4?md5=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70&id=62485

I need to get the requested URL so that i could verify the requested URL has the correct md5sum which makes the user watch the video. If it does not have the correct parameters then i should not allow the video to stream.

Any suggestions. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why do you post an other question for the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310917/how-to-assure-security-for-a-video-streaming-using-lighttpd)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create user/video specific folders and create symbolic links to the video files in those folders to get http://example.com/musiv-video/[md5sum]/video.mp4. Then you can serve the whole musiv-video folder. Note that anyone who can see the http requests can still see any of the videos so this is not really security measure, just something that makes access little more complicated. And make sure those urls are not found by Google search.

If you want to really restrict access, you need to create some better authentication scheme.